# How to add timer in tasks after being triggered in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am working on a slider in flutter which is focused on rating. I want to add a timer to manage a rating time (i.e if the user rated then he/she can't rate again for an hour. Which means once the function is triggered it won't trigger again for a specific time).

So how is it possible to do that. I have a little knowledge about the `Timer` class and I don't how exactly it should be done. By doing this we are bounding the user not to rate as many times as user want

Comment: Something like should be handled along with the server in a production system.

Comment: I told my team lead this. But he want to add this thing in flutter on client side to make prototype running and I don't know why

Comment: Okay, what is the state management system you're using, or If you want I can give you a general answer but that will need modification to work.

Comment: I need general answer. for state management I am using `setState((){})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple implementation using a `Timer` for the functionality you require is to store a `bool` and start the timer and toggle the `bool` value when the user performs the function and on timeout toggle the `bool to false and start the timer again.

Below is an example that uses `setState`.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home:TimerExample()));
}

class TimerExample extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _TimerExampleState();
  }
}

class _TimerExampleState extends State<TimerExample> {
   // Using a short timer for testing, set a duration 
   // you can set a any duration you like, For Example:
   // Duration(hours: 1) | Duration(minutes: 30)
   final _timeoutDuration = Duration(seconds:3);
   late Timer _timer;
   bool _canVote = true;

   @override
   void dispose() {
     super.dispose();
     _timer.cancel();
   }

   void onTimeout() {
    setState(() => _canVote = true);
   }
  
   void startTimer() {
     setState(() {
       _canVote = false;
       _timer = Timer(_timeoutDuration, onTimeout);
     });
   }
  
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return TextButton(
       onPressed: _canVote ? startTimer : null,
       child: Text('Vote')
     );
   }
}
```